# how to instantiate contract with initialSupply?

Tags: ink

I know this command, instantiate from cli, with initial 1,000,000 supply

```
cargo contract instantiate --constructor new --args 1_000_000 true --suri //Alice --salt $(date +%s)
```

To do the same thing with javascript how to do that??

```
// contract is already uploaded to contract node
let contractaddress = '5EfCU8ya9BMZsJYi2ktxDuNHNSu8YYqJbU1shJhhzCtwLM6D'

const { ContractPromise } = require('@polkadot/api-contract')
const contract = new ContractPromise(api, abi, contractaddress);


await api.tx.contracts.instantiateWithCode(10000000, codehash,'3000000000', 2000000, false,salt).signAndSend(alicePair);
```

it returns a object, Type(32) [Uint8Array] whats this...

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to instantiate a contract depending on the context.

1. If the contract has already been deployed then you can use a code hash, the contract address, and the [BlueprintPromise](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api-contract/start/basics) approach.
2. If the contract has not yet been deployed then you must upload the Wasm blob using [CodePromise](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api-contract/start/basics)
3. Finally you can use the [Contracts UI Wizard](https://contracts-ui.substrate.io/), then, once deployed, instantiate a JS contract instance in PolkadotJS using the contract address and metadata to make transactions and queries from the client.

[HERE](https://github.com/paritytech/contracts-ui/blob/master/src/helpers/contract.ts#L15)
is the code for Contracts UI that uses the first two cases mentioned above.

The `Type(32)` that you mentioned is related to the metadata from your compiled contract. If you look inside either your `Metadata.json` or `<contract_name>.contract` you will see a section called `types`. This describes the type interfaces unique to each contract so that the client library can correctly encode / decode the data.

There is some low level code going on, but we are working on ways to simplify this. useink is a React hooks library that handles all of the encoding / decoding in an opinionated and ergonomic way. There are some helper functions that work outside of React, which you might find useful. Capi is a JavaScript library that is currently under development and will have some great examples. `useink` will eventually use that under the hood.

Comment: Thank you so much